# flextable: set_header_df causes R session to crash

Tags: r, flextable

After a recent upgrade from R version 3.6.0 to R version 3.6.1, some flextable code I wrote started causing R to crash. I found some code from the flextable that also causes my session to crash.

```
library(flextable)

typology <- data.frame(
            col_keys = c(
                            "Sepal.Length",
                            "Sepal.Width",
                            "Petal.Length",
                            "Petal.Width",
                            "Species"
            ),
            type = c("double", "double", "double",  "double", "factor"),
            what = c("Sepal", "Sepal", "Petal",  "Petal", "Species"),
            measure = c("Length", "Width", "Length", "Width", "Species"),
            stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

ft <- flextable( head( iris ) )
ft <- set_header_df( ft, mapping = typology, key = "col_keys" )
```

Some functions like add_header_row are still working but set_header_df is not.

Help getting this working again would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you updated the packages?

Comment: Think all the packages are current. Had to reinstall packages when I upgraded my R. With the older version of R, I got warnings about packages being developed for a different version of R. I don't get that anymore for the newer R version. The upgrade to the new version of R took place in the last few days.

Comment: I can run your code as written. Are you using Rstudio? Maybe getting the latest Rstudio would help.

Comment: Your idea about RStudio seems like a good one. IT is having trouble installing the latest version. It seems to install but then fails to launch. Hopefully they'll get it resolved soon.

Comment: I just tried it in base R. Works there too. Opens the table in Chrome - I didn't know where it would be :-)

Comment: Thanks. Still trying to get an updated version of RStudio.